# Invalid expression with rawHTML handlebars

Tags: vuejs2, vue.js

I am attempting to input some raw HTML into a vue template.

I get these two errors...

```
ERROR in ./~/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler.js?id=data-v-7c43939e!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=template&index=0!./src/components/views/Find.vue

Vue template syntax error:

- invalid expression: {{{ github }}}

@ ./src/components/views/Find.vue 9:2-167
@ ./src/router/index.js
@ ./src/main.js
@ multi ./build/dev-client ./src/main.js
ERROR in ./~/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler.js?id=data-v-7c43939e!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=template&index=0!./src/components/views/Find.vue

Vue template syntax error:

- invalid expression: {{{ takeAction }}}

@ ./src/components/views/Find.vue 9:2-167
@ ./src/router/index.js
@ ./src/main.js
@ multi ./build/dev-client ./src/main.js
```

The code for the file can be seen here:

```
<template>
  <div id="find-help" class="container">
    <div>
      <p>{{{ github }}}</p>
      <p>{{{ takeAction }}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'find-help',
  data () {
    return {
      github: this.$t('views.find-help.paragraphs')[0],
      takeAction: this.$t('views.find-help.paragraphs')[1]
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.centered {
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  background: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  min-width: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
}
</style>
```

and the two translations are

```
"find-help": {
  "paragraphs": [
    "We are trying really hard to develop this page into an interactive map and events list. If you have any web development knowledge, we would love your help. Check our open source repository on <a href='http://www.github.com/openrefuge'>http://www.github.com/openrefuge</a>.",
    "If you cannot help with development, please look at the other areas we need help with on the 'Take Action' page. Thank you!."
  ]
}
```

Am I doing something wrong that does not allow for this?

I had been following the documentation for vue and found

- https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML

and following the triple handlebar syntax it should work.

Thanks for the help!

If you would like to look at a more complete implementation, please look at https://github.com/openrefuge/openrefuge/pull/11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triple handlebar is for Vue 1 and you are using [Vue 2](https://github.com/openrefuge/openrefuge/blob/91b8543f7cd9fe54344a33935ba6a19e398e221b/package.json#L16). Check [Vue 2 docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML).

Instead of `<p>{{{ github }}}</p>`, you need to do: `<p v-html="github"></p>`

Comment: I was not aware that I was on the 1 documentation!  Thank you.